# How to determine NumberPicker values based on month and year

Tags: android, numberpicker, android-number-picker

In my app, I am using `NumberPicker` with values in Hebrew and it looks like this:

[image]

The values are taken from an array like this:

```
 String times[] = {"ינו'-18", "פבר'-18", "מרץ-18", "אפר'-18", "מאי-18", "יוני-18", "יולי-18"
        , "אוג'-18", "ספט'-18", "אוק'-18", "נוב'-18", "דצמ'-18", "ינו'-19", "פבר'-19", "מרץ-19", "אפר'-19", "מאי-19", "יוני-19", "יולי-19"
        , "אוג'-19", "ספט'-19", "אוק'-19", "נוב'-19",};
```

The Hebrew values in the array correspond to the months like this :

- **ינו'**    is The first month in the year (January)
- **פבר'**    is the second month(February)
- **מרץ'**    is month 3 (march)
- **אפר**     is month 4 (April)
- **מאי**     is month 5 (May)
- **יוני**    is month 6 (June)
- **יולי**    is month 7 (July)
- **אוג**     is month 8 (August)
- **ספט**     is month 9 (september)
- **אוק**     is month 10 (october)
- **נוב**     is month 11 (November)
- **דצמ**     is month 12 (December)

I want to set my array values so it will start from the current month (for example if we are on June-2021 the first value will be יוני-2021) and will include all of the months in the next year as well.

At first, I thought of saving the array in remote database/locally with a lot of values but I realized that this is just a bad solution Because I will need to change the values in the array constantly.

**How can I know what values (combining both Hebrew and the year like above) do I need to put in the array according to the current month and year?**

**Here is some extra information -** here is the method that I am using to set the `numberpicker` values:

```
private void setNumberPicker(NumberPicker nubmerPicker, String[] numbers) {
    nubmerPicker.setMaxValue(numbers.length - 1);
    nubmerPicker.setMinValue(0);
    nubmerPicker.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
    nubmerPicker.setDisplayedValues(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I found a solution using a custom class that I made:

```
public class YearAndMontsForNumberPicker {
private String[] demoArray = {"ינו'-xx", "פבר'-xx", "מרץ-xx", "אפר'-xx", "מאי-xx", "יוני-xx", "יולי-xx"
        , "אוג'-xx", "ספט'-xx", "אוק'-xx", "נוב'-xx", "דצמ'-xx" , "ינו'-xx", "פבר'-xx", "מרץ-xx", "אפר'-xx", "מאי-xx", "יוני-xx", "יולי-xx"
        , "אוג'-xx", "ספט'-xx", "אוק'-xx", "נוב'-xx", "דצמ'-xx"};

private Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();  //get the proper replacements for the demo array
private int currentMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
private String currentYear = (c.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "").substring(2);
private String[] finalArray;


//sets the array that will be later use with numberPicker
public String[] setArrayForCurrentYear() {

    finalArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(demoArray, currentMonth, demoArray.length);

    changeArrayxx(finalArray,currentYear,0,12-currentMonth); //replace the first part with current year
    changeArrayxx(finalArray, (Integer.valueOf(currentYear)+1)+"",12-currentMonth,finalArray.length); //replace the end of the array with the next year

    return finalArray;
}

private void changeArrayxx(String [] array,String currentyear,int iterator,int condition){
    for (int i = iterator; i < condition; i++) { // chang the xx in the array with the last 2 digits
        array[i] = array[i].replace("xx", currentyear);
        }
    }
}
```

Now all if left to do get Instance of this class like this:

```
new YearAndMontsForNumberPicker().setArrayForCurrentYear()
```

For my case, I called this inside `setNumberPicker` method (check the question):

```
setNubmerPicker(currentYearNumberPicker, new YearAndMontsForNumberPicker().setArrayForCurrentYear());
```